# My anchor tag is not taking javascript function and my inline style sheet in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

```html
else { echo"
<td style='color:green' onclick=alert '('You have already send a request for buying this ticket ')'><a href='sell.php?buy=" . $b_id . "&usr=" . $buyer_id . "&sell=" . $s_id . "'> Resend Your detail </a>
</td>"; echo"

</tr>";
```

Please help to bind javascript with inline style sheet . Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick=\"javascript:alert('You have already send a request for buying this ticket')\"
```

Check this

```html
<div onclick="javascript:alert('You have already send a request for buying this ticket')">CLICK HERE </div>
```

EDIT: for link color green

```html
<a style='color:green'  href='sell.php?buy=" . $b_id . "&usr=" . $buyer_id . "&sell=" . $s_id . "'> Resend Your detail </a>
```

Comment: It is giving error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'javascript' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: escape the anchor tag double quotes like \"

Comment: Javascript is now working according to code of donald123 but how to add style please help on it now

Comment: style for 'Resend Your detail' or for your alert message?

Comment: Resend your detail on table display not on alert message

Answer (score 1):

In your task

```
 <td style='color:green' onclick=\"javascript:alert('You have already send a request for buying this ticket')\"><a href='sell.php?buy=" . $b_id . "&usr=" . $buyer_id . "&sell=" . $s_id . "'> Resend Your detail </a>
```

Btw your quoting-style is not optimal

Comment: Javascript is working now how to add style to this.I did not get your style point.

Answer (score 1):

```html
else { echo"
<td onclick=\ "javascript:alert('You details is resend ')\"><a style=\ "color:green\" href='sell.php?buy=" . $b_id . "&usr=" . $buyer_id . "&sell=" . $s_id . "'> Resend Your detail </a>"; echo"

  </tr>"; }
```

This Is right Answer problem solved

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick=\"javascript:alert('You have already send a request for buying this ticket')\"
```

Comment: Could you also explain your answer? Please edit your question with this information.